# Database global unique business key in postgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, uniqueidentifier, unique-key

i have several tables in a tablespace, such as t_a,t_b,t_c.
Each has a field name profile_id, is there any good method to generate unique keys for these tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most people who want what you describe use `uuid` keys - see the `ossp-uuid` extension for useful uuid generation functions.

Another alternative is to have a single sequence that you get keys from with `nextval`. All your key fields will want to be `bigint`. Just `CREATE SEQUENCE business_object_key_seq;`.

Neither of the above cases allow you to enforce global uniqueness without messing around with complicated triggers. Though neither will generate a duplicate key, so you won't get duplicates so long as your code doesn't do anything silly, and you can still enforce uniqueness within any given table.

Another approach used by some people is to have a table with a generated primary key and nothing else, or perhaps some kind of 'object_kind' field. This can serve as a foreign key reference. It might seem like this lets you enforce uniqueness, but in fact it's pretty useless because it doesn't stop you having a row with id=42 in both `t_a` and `t_b`.

Comment: if several tables use one sequence, is this will defect the performance of database?

Comment: It would make absolutely no difference at all. There's no locking involved with sequences, and no contention.